# How to get @test class context in data provider

Tags: testng

I found out that you can declare the data provider with ITestContext or java.lang.reflect.Method. as parameters but i want to know the class name of the test class for which the dataprovider method is called. Neither ITestContext nor java.lang.reflect.Method can provide that.

Comment: You basically want the class of the @Test method right?

Comment: Yes in the dataprovider. which is not a part of the test class.

Comment: My answer has been deleted - for I don't know what reasons!  Use method.getDeclaringClass() in the dataprovider.  It would give you the class of the test method.

Comment: Yes and that is java.lang.reflect.Method . I tried what u said. it gave that class in return. Not sure if i goofed up somewhere.

Comment: Marking it as an answer.  Not sure why someone would have deleted it.  Can you accept it just to make sure noone deletes it this time :)  really annoyed with the deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method.getDeclaringClass() should give you the method's class name in the dataprovider method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ITestNGMethod object as a parameter to your @DataProvider method. via which you should be able to extract out whatever you need.

Here's a sample

```
  public static Object[][] dataProvider(ITestNGMethod method) {
    Class cla = method.getRealClass();
    Method tm = method.getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
    Constructor constructor = method.getConstructorOrMethod().getConstructor();
    String name = cla.getName() + ".";
    if (tm == null) {
      name = constructor.getName();
    } else {
      name = name + tm.getName();
    }

    System.out.println("Data provider is being called  by " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](http://www.lysergicjava.com/?p=165) to my question. If anyone has a better answer let me know.

The solution is data providers can’t take arbitrary inputs but they can, however, accept a reference to the current test method.  So, we can create a new annotation, DataProviderArguments, which I could attach to a test method and then pass the class name in the argument.

create annotation

```
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;


    /**
    * Annotation for feeding arguments to methods conforming to the
    * "@DataProvider" annotation type.
    * @author jharen
    */
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface DataProviderArguments
    {
      /**
      * String array of key-value pairs fed to a dynamic data provider.
      * Should be in the form of key=value, e.g., <br />
      * args={"foo=bar", "biz=baz"}
      */
    String[] value();
    }
```

Create a helper class which will read the argument and pass them on .

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataProviderUtils
{
    protected static Map<String, String> resolveDataProviderArguments(Method testMethod) throws Exception
    {
        if (testMethod == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test Method context cannot be null.");

        DataProviderArguments args = testMethod.getAnnotation(DataProviderArguments.class);
        if (args == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test Method context has no DataProviderArguments annotation.");
        if (args.value() == null || args.value().length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test Method context has a malformed DataProviderArguments annotation.");
        Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.value().length; i++)
        {
            String[] parts = args.value()[i].split("=");
            arguments.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        return arguments;
    }
```

And with that,  FileDataProvider can read any given file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class FileDataProvider
{
    @DataProvider(name="getDataFromFile")
    public static Iterator<Object[]> getDataFromFile(Method testMethod) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, String> arguments = DataProviderUtils.resolveDataProviderArguments(testMethod);
        List<String> lines = FileDataProvider.getRawLinesFromFile(arguments.get("filePath"));
        List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            data.add(new Object[]{line});
        }
        return data.iterator();
    }

    public static List<String> getRawLinesFromFile(Method testMethod) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, String> arguments = DataProviderUtils.resolveDataProviderArguments(testMethod);
        return FileDataProvider.getRawLinesFromFile(arguments.get("filePath"));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<String> getRawLinesFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(is, "UTF-8");
        is.close();
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Finally write tests like this;

```
@Test(dataProviderClass=com.netflix.systemtests.api.commons.dataproviders.TestAccountDataProvider.class, dataProvider="getTestAccountsFromFile")
@DataProviderArguments("filePath=src/main/resources/input-files/testAccounts.txt")
public void fetchInstantQueueAsJSON(String email, String accountID) throws Exception
{
  // blah blah blah testy test goes here
}
```